# Pidgin is not working in squid proxy

Tags: proxy, squid, pidgin

I have setup a test lab with `Squid Proxy version 3.5.20`.

I have allowed `port 5222` in `squid proxy` but still `pidgin` is not communicating with `Openfire Server`.

Below the `Squid.conf` configuration.

```
acl SSL_ports port 443

acl Safe_ports port 80          # http

acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp

acl Safe_ports port 443         # https

acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher

acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais

acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports

acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt

acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http

acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker

acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http

acl CONNECT method CONNECT

acl im port 5222

http_access deny !Safe_ports

http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost

http_access allow localhost manager

http_access deny manager

http_access allow localnet

http_access allow localhost

http_access allow im

http_access deny all

http_port 3128

cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 20000 32 256

cache_mem 500 MB
```

Please help.

Comment: its worked fine after added acl Safe_ports port 5222 and removed the below lines,

Answer (score 0):

its worked fine after added

acl Safe_ports port 5222

and removed the below lines,

acl im port 5222

http_access allow im

Now configured pidgin with proxy settings.